# SharePoint and Power Automate trigger overide - When an item is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, power-automate

A PowerAutomate workflow as been created that triggers when a SharePoint item (list) is created which works ('When an item is created').
The problem is that an item has already been created in the list before the workflow was added.

Is it possible to trigger the workflow on an existing item in a list ? Perhaps with PowerShell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use the same logic on all previous items, as a workaround solution, I would suggest

- Duplicating the current flow to run on `When an item is updated`,
- Then add a condition to just apply the flow logic on items created before a specific date that is the date before creating the current flow!